# How to find the no. of String objects created in the java heap and in the String literal pool

Tags: java, string, jvm, heap-memory

Basically I need to find the no. of String objects created by my piece of code, in java heap and String pool.I don't need the entire String object count in the JVM. I only need the object count created by my code.

Suppose:

```
String string1 = "a";
String string2 = new String("a");
```

Then  the count of objects will be 2 in the heap and 1 entry in the string pool.(Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: What use can you possibly have for this?

Comment: I was going through the Java heap and String literals, this is basically for my own curiosity, if it is possible let me know.

Comment: If you really need this, the simplest answer may be to a Java Dump and analyze the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String pool may or may not be stored on the heap so you can't really oppose the two.

- `String s1 = "a"`

  => the string literal `"a"` will be in the string pool, and `s1` is a reference to that string instance
- `String s2 = new String("a")`

  => the string literal `"a"` is already in the pool, so no new string created there
  => `new String(...)` a new string is created which is not in the pool and `s2` is a reference to that instance

So in total: `"a"` in the pool and `new String("a")` not in the pool => 2 string instances in total.

Answer (score 0):

For `String s1 ="a"`, it will create an object in String Constant pool with the reference `s1` pointing to that object.

For `String s2 = new String("a")`, it will create an object in Heap area with the reference `s2` pointing to that object. Then in String Constant pool already `"a"` has an object so it directly pointing to that.(ie)In String Constant pool duplicates objects are not allowed. So in this case 2 Object will be created.